# Using multiple letters as a whole for delimating some text

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, find

I have a html file, which contains lots of /<|^, some texts beside garbage headers, words, etc.  I want to extract some texts between a set of letters, such as "nbsp" and a pipe "|".  I lose information if I use "delims=nbsp" since delims think them as "n", "b", "s", and "p".  How should I approach the problem, and how can I extract numerous texts?

Example text:

```
garbage nbsp; SOME_TEXT_1 | garbage
garbage nbsp; SOME_TEXT_2 | garbage
garbage nbsp; SOME_TEXT_3 | garbage
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text is really as simple as your example, this will do it;

```
for /f "delims=^|; tokens=2" %a in (garbage.txt) do echo %a
```

If the surrounding text contains more semicolons, you're probably easier off getting a windows version of sed or awk. Or any decent text editor, if it's a one time job.